# Can not install ggplot package in R 2.14.1

Tags: r

I was trying to install package gplots on ubuntu R 2.14.1

```
install.packages('gplots')
```

And I receive this message:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘gplots’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)
```

I might assume that this is local problem only with this version, because other people are able to install it properly. I tried to find solution with google search, but nothing looks similar.

Are there any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: With the release of R 3.0.0 this will probably be a vFAQ in the coming months. Many packages needed to be updated for the major version change. and the CRAN repositories will have often dropped their out-of-date directories.

Comment: One more option for intstalling `gplots` on Ubuntu that worked for me: `sudo apt-get install r-cran-gplots`. I got the idea from [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473741/install-gdata-failed-on-64-bit-linux).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the archived gplots versions [here](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/gplots). Just grab an old version, that should install fine. Alternatively, add the ubuntu repository that CRAN provides to you sources.list and upgrade R to version 3.0. After that installing `gplots` should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-in-library-gplots-there-is-no-package-called-gplots-td1690367.html . It seems the version of R you are using might not be compatible with the package "gplots".