# Installing newest older compatible version R of package

Tags: r, package

[Installing older version of R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082341/installing-older-version-r-package) shows how to install a different version of an R package.

Can that be automated so I can have it install the newest (older) version that is compatible with my R installation?

In my case I need it for Rcpp, but a general solution working for any package would be preferred.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? What version of R are you running, and why isn't the latest version?

Comment: I posted an untested function as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091304/efficiently-getting-older-versions-of-r-packages. The function itself is somewhat incomplete, but I have added some notes about what I think should be done for further development.

Comment: @Thomas I need the function for distributing software: I will not know which version of R my users have.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I get: Error in install_archive("reshape") : could not find function "htmlParse"

Comment: @OleTange Run `install.packages('XML')`.

Comment: @Thomas > install_archive("reshape")
Loading required package: devtools
Downloading reshape_0.8.3.tar.gz from http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/reshape_0.8.3.tar.gz
Error: client error: (404) Not Found

Comment: The link you want is: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/reshape/reshape_0.8.3.tar.gz. You should update @AnandaMahto's function accordingly (it's missing the "/reshape/" portion of the URL).