# using R package 'effects' in R version 3.4.4

Tags: r, package, version, effects

Currently, I'm using R version 3.4.4.
And I'm trying to use R package 'effects'.
But I can't install & use this package on this version.

```
code
install.packages("effects")
library(effects)
plot(allEffects(lm_g_sc), type="response")
```

results

> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘effects’ is not available
>   (for R version 3.4.4)

What can I do?
If I can't use this package, there are some alternative packages?

Comment: If you can't upgrade R, you'll need to install an [older version of the package](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/effects/) from source (requires an installation of Rtools). This could mean that you also need older versions of its dependencies. It might be easiest to use a CRAN snapshot: https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a result of a [related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766923/), I built a package specifically for this purpose, `oldr`. The package is available here:

https://github.com/duckmayr/oldr

You can install via

```
devtools::install_github("duckmayr/oldr")
```

Once the package is installed, you just need to run

```
oldr::install.compatible.packages("effects")
```

The function `oldr::install.compatible.packages()` searches through the CRAN archives to find the newest version of the package that is compatible with your installed version of R.