# I need a function in 'cmprsk' package but it not available for v3.5.2. Is there any workaround for this?

Tags: r, package, installation, install.packages

I'm trying to load the 'survminer' package in R, but this package depends on the 'cmprsk' package which is not available for version 3.5.2.

I have already tried using code similar to below.

```
packageurl <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/cmprsk/cmprsk_2.2-8.tar.gz"
install.packages("https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cmprsk", contriburl=NULL,
                 type="source")
install.packages('cmprsk', dependencies=T)
```

I need to install and load 'cmprsk' into R

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa). You can check out my [`oldr`](https://github.com/duckmayr/oldr) package which is made to help with this. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982174/using-r-package-effects-in-r-version-3-4-4/51983174#51983174)