# Error installing gplots

Tags: r, gplots

I am running R (v. 3.0.3) on OSX (v. 10.9.2).

When trying to install the 'gplots' package in R studio with the following command, I get an error:

```
> library("gplots")
Error in library("gplots") : there is no package called ‘gplots’
```

I have seen others having the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091096/can-not-install-ggplot-package-in-r-2-14-1), but updating to the newest R version as suggested did not solve the problem

Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first need to install the package before you can call it from your library. Try:

```
install.packages("gplots")
```

Then, you can run your library command using:

```
library(gplots)
```

Comment: Downloading it from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots/index.html or https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html gives a zip but that doesn't have an installer.