# package ‘gplots’ is not available for R version 3.0.2

Tags: r, package, gplots

I was using ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. My R version was 3.0.2.
When I used the following command to install package "gplots"

```
sudo -i
R
install.packages("gplots")
```

I got a warning message: package ‘gplots’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2.) Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997535/error-installing-gplots

Comment: Nop. I did tried to install before using the package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing gpots from github cran repo.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(devtools)
install_github("cran/gplots")
```